# To move a new file in a folder when the transfer is done

Tags: bash, sftp

I will rent a server. Some people will upload some files to their allocated folders (I'm thinking of using `sftp`), and at the moment the file transfer is done, I want to move it to my folder in the server. I can detect if there is a new file or not with `watch`, but when the transfer starts, the file appears there and my script moves it immediately, so before the file transfer is done. How can I prevent this? How can I write a script that understands the transfer is done? Can `sftp` create a log? Maybe I can try to detect that log to move the files. Thank you in advance.

Comment: take a look at this https://serverfault.com/a/415599/482932

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `inotifywait` can achieve what you're after - it has the capability to wait until a file write has finished before executing a command.

The following will continuously watch a folder for new files and execute the command in the loop when writing to the file has finished.

```
WATCH_DIR=/directory/to/monitor
DEST_DIR=/x/y/z

/usr/bin/inotifywait --recursive --monitor --quiet -e moved_to -e close_write --format '%w%f' "$WATCH_DIR" | while read -r INPUT_FILE; do

mv "$0" "$DEST_DIR"

done
```

For more configuration options see https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywatch